# How to rearrange widgets on gridstack after delete a widget

Tags: javascript, gridstack

How can I trigger 'rearrange position' on gridstack after delete a widget because whenever I delete some widget that is between others, there's a gap left between the remaining widgets.

Something like jquery.shapeshift 'ss-rearrange'.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: did you get a solution for this?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi    nope I had to redraw the widgets in order to arrange them

Comment: @vnv_nation how did you do that. will you please share your code or link

Answer (score 0):

You can call `compact()` on grid or set the option `float: false`.

Depends on your needs and version of Gridstack.